# Output on more rows in R

Tags: r

I have a text inside a dataframe that does not fit in the page I get doing the report. Is there a way to display it on more rows?

As an example

```
This sentence is way to long to fit on one row, it would be a lot better having it on multiple lines, like two, three, or maybe four
```

Should be output like:

```
This sentence is way to long to fit on one row, 
it would be a lot better having it on multiple lines, like two,
three, or maybe four
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_wrap`

```
library(stringr)
cat(str_wrap(str1, width = 40))
This sentence is way to long to fit on
one row, it would be a lot better having
it on multiple lines, like two, three,
or maybe four
```

---

Or it can be split

```
strsplit(str_wrap(str1, width = 40), '\n')[[1]]
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "This sentence is way to long to fit on one row, it would be a lot better having it on multiple lines, like two, three, or maybe four"
```

Comment: @Mauretto If you want to split, then `strsplit(str_wrap(str1, width = 40), '\n')[[1]]`

Comment: @Mauretto If it to print, you can use `cat` as in the updated answer or wanted to split, use `strsplit`